# VtaskSuspenAll - Atomicity related ticket on FreeRTOS

Tags: freertos, stm32f4

I'm working with FreeRTOS kernel on a STM32F469 Target. 
I have a hard fault and I suppose it's due to VtaskSuspendAll. 
I've read this ticket : [click here](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/September_2013/freertos_Concerns_about_the_atomicity_of_vTaskSuspendAll_d165e9c3j.html) 
How can I know if "writing from the register back into the memory is atomic" ? Because I understand that otherwhise it can be a problem and I guess my writings are not atomic.

The problem occurs when I'm using xEventGroupSetBitsFromISR() inside a timer interrupt...

I don't know how to investigate on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Start here https://www.freertos.org/FAQHelp.html which documents a whole load of common issues and how to catch them.  There are some very specifics for STM32 in regards to setting up the number pre-emption bits in the hardware, etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ARMv7M Architecture Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0403/latest), Chapter "A3.5.3 Atomicity in the ARM architecture", reads and writes to bytes, halfwords and words are atomic. Read-Modify-Write Cycles are *not* atomic.

The mentioned ticket states:

> Basically the key to this is that each task maintains its own context, and a context switch cannot occur if the variable is non zero.  So, as long as the writing from the register back into the memory is atomic, it is not a problem.

Therefore, as long as `uxSchedulerSuspended` is byte/halfword/word, the access should work.

Use a JTAG debugger, put a breakpoint in the hardfault handler, and backtrace to where the fault happened. Examine the Registers `CFSR`, `MMFAR` and `BFAR` to learn more about what happened.